# Странное поведение RecyclerView во фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

В `RecyclerView` выводился список, который получался парсингом. Находился этот `RecyclerView`во фрагменте(например `FragmentTeam`), который являлся частью `Navigation Drawer`. Всё отлично работало. Но понадобилось расширить эту часть приложения и добавить табы. Получилось так, что в новом фрагменте(например `FragmentHome`) образовались 3 таба, под одним из которых тот `FragmentTeam`, а под 2мя другими соответственно 2 других фрагмента. В этом случае `RecyclerView` стал вести себя странным образом, а именно:

1. Высота последнего элемента списка `RecyclerView`,который виден в данный момент на экране, стала равна величине экрана, после того как начинаешь список двигать вниз.
2. При пролистывании табов ко 2му, а потом и к 3му, при возврате снова на 2й запускается AsyncTask из `FragmentTeam`(судя по появляющимуся `progressdialog`) и при возврате на 1й таб, элементы `RecyclerView` имеют нормальную высоту. Но как только снова начинаешь двигать список дальше, всё повторяется как в п.1

В связи с этим вопрос. Что это такое?) И как с этим бороться? Если нужный фрагменты кода, то добавлю, просто не знаю какой именно кусок стоит показать.

Фрагменты кода.

Разметка, содержащая RecyclerView (*fragent_team_roster.xml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Разметка, содержащая TabLayout (*fragent_team_list.xml*):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TeamFragment">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarteam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/TankTheme"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/TankTheme"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarteam" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Фрагмент,запускающий AsyncTask (*TeamRosterFragment.java*):

```
public class TeamRosterFragment extends Fragment {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    HashMap<String, String> map ;
    Context context;
    private List<Playcard> playcardList = new ArrayList<>();
    private PlaycardAdapter pAdapter;

    // URL Address
    String url = "http://...";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team_roster, container, false);

        // RecyclerView Setup
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        pAdapter = new PlaycardAdapter(context,playcardList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(pAdapter);

        pAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new PlaycardAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {

                String fio = playcardList.get(position).getFio();
                String pos = playcardList.get(position).getPos();
                String num = playcardList.get(position).getNum();
                String link = playcardList.get(position).getLink();
                String photo = playcardList.get(position).getPhoto();


                Intent intent = new Intent(TeamRosterFragment.this.getActivity(), SingleItemView.class);
                intent.putExtra("fio", fio);
                intent.putExtra("pos", pos);
                intent.putExtra("num", num);
                intent.putExtra("link", link);
                intent.putExtra("photo", photo);

                TeamRosterFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

        new JsoupListView().execute();
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    private void preparePlaycardData() {
        playcardList.add(new Playcard(map.get("fio"),map.get("num"),
                map.get("pos"),map.get("photo"),
                map.get("link")));
    }


    // Внутренний классJsoupListView с потоком AsyncTask
    private class JsoupListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            try {

                // Connect to the Website URL
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                int coun=0;//с помощью счётчика отделим официальные лица

                //парсим и загоняем в map
                for (Element table : doc.select("div[class=roster-view]")) {
                    if (coun>1)
                        break;
                    for (Element item : table.select("div[class=roster-view_itemContent]")) {


                        for (Element item_fio : item.select("div[class=roster-view_fio]")) {
                            map.put("fio", item_fio.text());

                        }

                        for (Element item_info : item.select("div[class=roster-view_info]")) {
                            //    map.put("info", item_info.text());

                            String str = item_info.text();
                            String str_num = "";
                            String str_pos = "";
                            char c;
                            int count = 0;

                            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                                c = str.charAt(i);

                                if (count == 1) {
                                    str_pos = str_pos + c;
                                    if (c == ' ')
                                        break;
                                } else if (c == ' ') {
                                    count++;
                                    //i++;
                                    str_pos = str_pos + c;
                                } else
                                    str_num = str_num + c;
                            }
                            map.put("num", str_num);
                            map.put("pos", str_pos);

                        }

                        for (Element item_photo : item.select("div[class=roster-view_photo]")) {
                            Elements imgSrc = item_photo.select("img[src]");
                            String imgSrcStr1 = imgSrc.attr("src");
                            String imgSrcStr = "http:" + imgSrcStr1;

                            map.put("photo", imgSrcStr);
                        }

                        for (Element item_link : item.select("div[class=roster-view_fio]")) {
                            Elements url_href = item_link.select("a[href]");
                            String url1 = url_href.attr("href");
                            String link = "http://laf.amfoot.ru" + url1;
                            map.put("link", link);

                        }
                        coun++;

                        preparePlaycardData();
                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: По первому вопросу добавьте разметку, содержащую `RecyclerView` и разметку, в которой определены табы. По второму вопросу, добавьте код фрагмента, запускающий `AsyncTask`. Интересуют в первую очередь методы, имеющие отношение к жизненному циклу фрагмента (типа `onCreateView`)

Comment: @Agrgg, добавил код

Comment: Есть какие-то мысли?) Я просто в ступоре.

Comment: Ну с асинк таской всё понятно. Она вызывается в `onCreateView`, который вызывается каждый раз, когда пэйджер перелистывается на фрагмент. [В интернете пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13414482/3100967), что самое простое решение использовать [`setOffscreenPageLimit(numberOfTabs)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) и просто закешировать все фрагменты, чтобы у них не пересоздавалась вьюха

Comment: @Agrgg, да, с п.2(про AsyncTask) всё закэшировалось, хоть это и не решение, т.к. всплывал этот таск во 2м фрагменте, в котором кода-то и нет никакого, кроме того, что создала сама студия! А вот с  высотой элементов RecyclerView чудеса остаются не решаемыми) Есть такая вероятность, что данное поведение ресайклера связано с тем, что пришлось вкладывать фрагмент во фрагмент?